# How to group a regular expression in re.split() function?

Tags: python, regex, split

See two examples how re.split() works:

```
>>> re.split(',', 'a,b')
['a', 'b']
```

but

```
>>> re.split('(,)', 'a,b')
['a', ',', 'b']
```

Why I get ',' in the list? How to avoid it?

I am asking, because I would like to make a split using an expression similar to 'xy(a|b)cd'.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group, like:

```
re.split('(?:,)', 'a,b')
```

Comment: Thanks. It works (Athrough still I don't understand why normal parenthesis resulted in ',' in the list).

Comment: @cauchy, because capturing groups (parenthesis) capture their content (which is included in the split results as an element for each capturing group and split match, per definition).

Comment: So if I want a backreference within my split() pattern I'm SOL?

Answer (score 2):

It works that way because it’s [documented to work that way](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#re.split):

> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the text of all groups in
>   the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.